# MongoDB not returning all objects from

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am using it with the Node.js driver.
Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var app = express();
var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017, {'native_parser' : true}));

var db = mongoclient.db('test');
app.get('/', function(request, response) {                                                         

db.collection('firstImport').find().each(function(err, data){
    if(data != null)response.send(data);
});
});


var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
mongoclient.open(function (err, mongoclient){
if (err) throw err;

app.listen(8080);
console.log("Express server started on 8080")
});
```

I would like to return all results in my firstImport collection to the webpage but this is only returning the first result.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toArray()` :

```
db.collection('firstImport').find().toArray(function(err, data){
    if(data != null)response.send(data);
});
```

Comment: THIS WORKED RIGHT AWAY!
Once more question, if my objects are in standard format `{a:2, b:3, c:4}`
How would I get the results of `data.a`?
response.send(data.a) does not return any values.

Comment: `console.log(data)` and post what it shows, probably something simple :)

Comment: @MonsterWimp757 -- The most likely answer is, since it's returning an array, try `data[0].a`

Comment: for some reason this is only returning a for first result in the array - it only returns 2 and not 3, 4, ...
**Edit**
Okay so I got confused - I am only seeing the first one because data[0] represents the first object in the toArray().

Comment: so it seems I found the real problem.  I made a for loop here:

`for(i in data){
            console.log(data[i].a);
        }` and it works perfect

but if I change this to:

`for(i in data){
            response.send(data[i].a);
        }`
It will only return the first value.
Any idea as to why it would behave differently?

Comment: Of course, `for in` is used to iterate over an objects keys, but you have an array, so you just want a regular `for` loop. You can use the `for in` loop as an inner loop of your `for`, such as `for (var key in data[i])` since you're looping over objects. @MonsterWimp757

Comment: Yes the standard for loop works perfectly to log the output but when I  change the `console.log()` to `response.send()` it will not serve anything but the first object when it should be looping through the entire length of data.  The inner loop `for(var key in data[i])` will only return the key values, so how would I get the value of these keys?  To `console.log(key)` returns the parameter names but I need the values.

Comment: Send the entire object back to the client-side if you need it.

Comment: Okay - I think I got it.  This is my code:

`app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  //var fs = require('fs');                                                                                   
  //var buf = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');                                                          
    db.collection('firstImport').find().toArray(function(err, data){
 var silo = [];
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            if(data[i].a != "")silo.push(data[i].a);
        }
        response.send(silo);
    });
});`

Thanks again for your help!